# Expected value from cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

Hey I have cumulative distribution function:

$$F(x)=\cases{0, x\le 0 \\ \Phi(\ln(x)), x\in (0,18) \\ \Phi(18), x\in [18, 24) \\1, x\ge 24 }$$

Where $\Phi$ is cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution. How to find Expected value of this distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the distribution is nonnegative, you can use this [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Basic_properties) for the expectation of a nonnegative random variable given its CDF $F$.

$$E[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X \ge x) \, dx = \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx.$$